# Dynamic Allocation of Array Inside of a Function

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to malloc and initialize an array, and return it to the calling function through the passed in pointer. (g++)

Ex:

```
float* buff;
allocateBuff(&buff);
buff[0] = 2.3;
free(buff);

int allocateBuff(float** buffer)
{
  *buffer = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*1);

   return 0;
}
```

However, this seg faults.

Comment: `malloc()`, `free()` in `c++`? Not at all a good practice. However, can you provide us with more information by using `gdb`?

Comment: works fine (no segfaults) for me using `g++ 4.8.1`

Comment: Hmm, ok I wonder whats wrong with my g++

Comment: Have you forgotten about `#include <cstdlib>` while using a machine with 64-bit pointers and 32-bit `int`s?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar without `#include <cstdlib>` it will give compile error not segfault

Comment: Can you try buff[0] = (float)2.3;

Comment: Also, didn't mention but I'm using the following flag  g++ -std=c++0x

Comment: I have tried on g++ 4.8.3, and no seg fault.

Comment: @user1475729 You should decide if you want [tag:C] or [tag:C++]...

Comment: @Dere0405 As the compiler knows that `buff[0]` is a `float`, that would be pointless.

Comment: Please post complete code that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `function return` must **match the type of pointer** you wish to return. If you want to allocate an array of `float`, then your function must be of type `float *`. The following is a quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *allocateBuff(float** buffer, int size)
{
    /* allocate array of floats */
    *buffer = calloc(size, sizeof(*buffer));

    return *buffer;
}

int main() {

    float *array = NULL;
    array = allocateBuff (&array, 10);

    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
        array[i] = (float)i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
        printf ("array [%d] : %f\n", i, array[i]);

    if (array) free (array);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/initfloat
array [0] : 0.000000
array [1] : 1.000000
array [2] : 2.000000
array [3] : 3.000000
array [4] : 4.000000
array [5] : 5.000000
array [6] : 6.000000
array [7] : 7.000000
array [8] : 8.000000
array [9] : 9.000000
```

---

Additionally, there is no need to pass `buffer` to the function at all. You can just as easily define your function as:

```
float *allocateBuff (int size)
{
    /* allocate array of floats */
    float *buffer = calloc (size, sizeof(*buffer));

    return buffer;
}
```

and then initialize your array in your code with:

```
float *array = NULL;
array = allocateBuff (10);
```

Comment: There is no need to actually return the pointer if it can be passed by value, as the OP does.

Comment: You are 100% correct. That is the difference between passing the `address of the buffer` as an argument or not. If the address is passed as an argument, then there is no need to assign the return.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the code above does work, it was seg faulting elsewhere. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger. Running the program with a debugger shows you the exact place where the segfault occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int allocate(float **buffer)
{
    *buffer = new float(2.3f);
    return 0;
}

int allocateAsArray(float **buffer, unsigned size)
{
    *buffer = new float[size];
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    float* buff = nullptr;
    // some operations ...
    delete buff;
    // or delete[] buff;
    return 0;
}
```

But using C-type pointers isn't a good idea in C++ (we prefer smart pointers / STL arrays for more safety).